# Shape key creation + high-low poly baking on sculpts?

Tags: animation, sculpting, baking, shape-keys

If I got a high poly sculpted character is it better to do the low poly baking then create shape keys? Do the shape keys then bake? How do I ensure the character will maintain proper shapekey "physics" if many of the faces it relies on are now simplified?

Simply put; is it better workflow to make the shape keys before baking? Or after? This end goal is to make a character creator in ue but I want to do all the shape key stuff in blender. I just don't want to put the effort in for these high poly sculpted shape keys and have it not be chill. And I don't want to put the work in to low poly this dude and have it not be detailed enough for me making shape keys.

Any tips, advice or help appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you make the shapekeys before or after baking, although making them afterwards will make it easier to visualize the full results.  You make shapekeys on the low poly only.  Your low poly needs sufficient density for whatever shapes you want to make.  There's no reason to make shapekeys for the high poly.  They don't interact with the bake process at all.

Comment: And answered. Thank you sir.